# Linking issue when prebuilt static and shared libraries with the Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, dynamic-linking

I have a program I am porting that links together multiple libraries when creating the executable.  I have built all those libraries using the stand alone toolchain and using the standalone toolchain I am able to create an executable that works on an android device.  So, it seems like the libraries I have built are functional.  Now I am trying to incorporate those libraries with an app.  So, in my android.mk I have something like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
ROOT_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)

include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PATH = $(ROOT_PATH)

LOCAL_MODULE    := test-libs

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := staticA
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := sharedA sharedB sharedC sharedD
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test-libs.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

For each of the libraries, I have a Android.mk like this

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := sharedA

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libsharedA.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The static library and one of the shared libraries have no dependencies on anything and if I only include them all is cool.  One shared prebuilt library is dependent on the static prebuilt library only and the others are dependent on the prebuilt static library and other prebuilt shared libraries.

The problem is if I load any that are dependent on the static library via System.loadLibrary() I get the useful message:

```
Unable to dlopen(libsharedA.so) Cannot load library: link_image
```

Digging through this and following the suggestions here about how to use strace:

http://mpigulski.blogspot.com/2010/09/debugging-dlopen-unsatisfiedlinkerror.html

I  found that when the shared libraries are loaded, they cannot locate a function that is in my static library.

So, how do I correctly use a prebuilt shared library whose use is dependent on a prebuilt static library and not have this issue?

Comment: have you tried to load the static library before loading the ones that depend on that one?

Comment: How?  I thought System.loadLibrary() was for shared libraries only.  I thought static libraries were handled differently, automatically.  I can try using loadLibrary tomorrow, but I don't think that works.

Comment: It's just a guess - I don't know if that really works. I was thinking that you need to load the library into some kind of java context so the other one knows where to look for to resolve what it is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared libraries should not depend on static libraries.

Static libraries are for linking (at compile-time) into an executable, not for adding at runtime.

If your shared library A uses a static library B, then either build a shared version of B or include B when you link A together.

Comment: Remade the shared libraries with -lstaticlib and got pat that.