# Resolving Circular Dependency in Android makefile

Tags: android, ndk-build

We are working on a project where we need to create a shared library from the static libraries. The issues we are facing is the static libraries contains a circular dependency. Following is the sample of my makefile:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
LOCAL_MODULE := Mylib1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libMylib1.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

           ....

           ....

           ....

LOCAL_MODULE  := DisplayDriver

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \

            file1.c \
            file2.c \
            file3.c

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := -Wl,--start-group \

                       Mylib1 \
                       Mylib2 \
                       Mylib3 \
                       Mylib4 \
                      -Wl,--end-group


LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=  \

           $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
           $(LOCAL_PATH)/examples \


LOCAL_CFLAGS := -x c -DHAVE_STDINT -DHAVE_SETENV -DNDEBUG -c

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog

APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I give the ndk-build V=1 I can see in the output that clearly -Wl,--start-group and -Wl,--end-group is removed from the compilation when it is going to create the shared library. So is there any other flags which is obvious and I am missing the same?

I am using NDK R9 on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: *[Android NDK: how to link multiple 3rd party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637450/android-ndk-how-to-link-multiple-3rd-party-libraries)* is not strictly a duplicate, but the [accepted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668373/192373) resolves this question, too.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that `-Wl,--start-group` specified in LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES is ignored.

There use to be LOCAL_GROUP_STATIC_LIBRARIES which would group static libraries with `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` when linking.

Now (ndk-10c) the only relevant variable is LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES which uses the linker flag `--whole-archive`.

> This is generally useful when there are circular dependencies between several static libraries. Note that when used to build a shared library, this will force all object files from your whole static libraries to be added to the final binary. This is not true when generating executables though.

Not exactly the same thing but may solve the dependency problem.

In my project, I've created a dedicated cpp file which explicitly references the problematic symbols.

```
auto i_reference_you =
{
    (void *)MyClass::some_symbol,
    (void *)some_other_symbol
};
```

This works for me because there are only a few symbols. It's nothing elegant but saves me from fighting the build system.